# ColumnarBatch DataSource failing with Pushdown columns

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing a DataSource that implements SupportsScanColumnarBatch, SupportsPushDownFilters, and SupportsPushDownRequiredColumns.

I am getting with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException deep inside of Spark after populating a ColumnarBatch with the same number of ColumnVectors as the length of requiredSchema provided in the pruneColumns override.

I suspect that Spark is looking for as many ColumnVectors as the column schema returned by readSchema override instead of using the schema provided by pruneColumns.

Doing a "select * from dft" works fine since the schema lengths are the same -- 15 columns in my test case. Anything less (e.g., "select col1, col2 from dft") returns the following stack trace, where it is clear that Spark is looking for more columns.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch.column(ColumnarBatch.java:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.datasourcev2scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any clues how I can get around this? For the time being, in order to get things to continue to run, I am ignoring the pruneColumns call and returning everything.

Comment: facing the same issue with Spark 2.3.1...

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, but it seems like a bit of a kludge.

What I did was create a ColumnVector array of the same length as the original schema (not the pruned columns), and ONLY populated the pruned columns, leaving the others in their original allocated state.

For example, if only columns with indexes 0, 5, and 9 of the original schema are in the pruned list, this is all that is required.

```
var cva = new Array[ColumnVector](schema.length)
cva(0).putLongs(...)
cva(5).putInts(...)
cva(9).putFloats(...)
var batch = new ColumnarBatch(cva)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a saner approach...

In your implementation of `SupportsPushDownRequiredColumns` let the `readSchema()` method return the same `StructType` you are getting in the `pruneColumns()` call!

Basically feedback what you got from Spark!

HTH

Comment: It works a charm! I shook my head when I wrote the workaround say "this can't be the answer"! Thank you very much. The datasource I'm writing is to read from a column-store database, so the ColumnarBatch approach is extremely fast.